# Resolve .net core injection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have an interface IRabbitSender and the implementation RabbitSender

```
public class RabbitSender : IRabbitSender(){
     
   public RabbitSender(string connection, string queue){
          
   }

   public void Send (object info){ // send message to specific queue }

}
```

I need different instances of the RabbitSender that will send information for different queues/connections.
But I only know which instance choose in runtime.

How can I do the DI? Actually, I have this, but I don't know how to distinct both and how to resolve the dependency in runtime.

```
 services.AddTransient<IRabbitSender>(s => new RabbitSender(connection1, queueName1));
 services.AddTransient<IRabbitSender>(s => new RabbitSender(connection2, queueName1));
```

Comment: At which point runtime? Application start? Each time you need it? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to take here. Here are two to consider.

1. Consider making the interface generic:

```cs
IRabbitSender<TMessage>
```

This allows the consumer specifying which message to send, and in your configuration you can map message types to queues (tip: try keeping message names and queue names in sync as a convention; that drastically simplifies your life):

```cs
// Handy extension method
public static AddSender<TMessage>(
    this IServiceCollection services, string con, string queue)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IRabbitSender<TMessage>(new RabbitSender(con, queue);
}

// Registrations
services.AddSender<ShipOrder>(connection1, queueName1);
services.AddSender<CancelOrder>(connection2, queueName1);
```

2. Inject the full list queues into RabbitSender

Another option is to inject the mapping of messages types to queue information into `RabbitSender`. For instance:

```cs
public class RabbitSender : IRabbitSender {
   private Dictionary<Type, (string connection, string queue)> senders;
   public RabbitSender(Dictionary<Type, (string connection, string queue)> senders){
       this.senders = senders;
   }

   public void Send(object info) {
       var queueInfo = this.senders[info.GetType];
       // TODO: Use queue info to send message to a queue
   }
}

// Registration
servies.AddSingleton<IRabbitSender>(new RabbitSender(new Dictionary
{
    { typeof(ShipOrder), (connection1, queueName1) }
    { typeof(CancelOrder), (connection2, queueName1) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to new up your `RabbitSender` class when you register instance it should be unique to. For example:

```
services.AddTransient<IRequireUniqueRabbit>(_ => {
   return new RequireUniqueRabbit(new RabbitSender(connString1, queue1))
});

services.AddTransient<IRequireUniqueRabbit2>(_ => {
   return new RequireUniqueRabbit2(new RabbitSender(connString2, queue2))
});
```

PS: Think about how you register classes holding the RabbitMQ connection, if you register them as `transient` or `scoped` they will dispose rabbitMQ connection each time they are disposed, most likely you want to avoid that